# No audio out from Raspberry Pi Zero HDMI output

Tags: audio

I am using an HDMI to HDMI plus audio converter at the HDMI output of a Raspberry Pi Zero. The video works fine, but I get no audio in headphones connected to the 3.5 mm jack output of the converter - I checked the converter with a DVD player HDMI output, and it works fine.

Comment: It may be that there's not enough current available from the Pi's HDMI socket to power the converter. Can you confirm it working with another Pi?

Comment: Add **hdmi_force_edid_audio=1** to your config.txt file on boot partition. Reboot and check. This will force your audio output to HDMI.

Comment: Hi, did you ever happen to check @Huczu 's suggestion? If it works that should be turned into an answer. Thanks.